# How to discrete animate GridLength from "Auto" to "*"?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, gridlength

I need to animate this property using a `Storyboard`.
Is writing your own animation is a best choice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is quite possible using the standard XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="col0"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="sbCol0ToAuto">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                BeginTime="0" Duration="0"
                Storyboard.TargetName="col0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                     </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
...
</Grid>
```

And even easier back to Auto:

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static GridLength.Auto}">
```

Comment: Except this won't actually animate anything as it won't interpolate between objects/structs like this.  Also, you can shorthand this as Value="*", you don't need to declare the GridLength struct.  If you really want to animate it you'll need your own animation.